# C# WPF ListView как изменить цвет и внешний вид шапки?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Подскажите как изменить внешний вид шапки с наименьшими затратами, чтобы у нее поставить свой цвет и чтобы у нее был плоский вид

Comment: Что конкретно имеется ввиду? Покажите на скриншоте

Comment: я не могу вставить скрин сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите стиль `GridViewColumnHeader`, к примеру следующим образом:

```
<Style x:Key="GridView.ColumnHeader.TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Nova" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Ну и дальше применяем:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridView.ColumnHeader.TestStyle}" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Test"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <TextBlock>Item 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Item 2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Item 3</TextBlock>
</ListView>
```

Результат:
[image: Result]

Comment: EvgeniyZ  извините а куда прописать верхний блок

Comment: @vova-forum [WPF | Стили](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/10.php).

Comment: Извиняюсь ,  все ОК, большое спасибо , все получилось